# What is the power density of graphite user the Wigner effect?

Tags: organic-chemistry, energy, materials, nuclear, nuclear-chemistry

The energy that graphite released upon a cascade of defects by neutron radiation is 2.7 MJ/Kg, however there is no data on how quick this energy is released. I am interested in this as this not mentioned anywhere on the Windscale disaster

Comment: For those of us who had never heard of the Windscale disaster: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windscale_fire.

Comment: No actual facts, but relaxation of an interstitial atom to an available hole is rather instantaneous. Thus the reaction is limited by the diffusion of holes. (diffusion of interstitials would be orders of magnitude slower). Diffusions of either kind is slow in graphite, as the recrystallization temperature indicates. Combine these opinions into; rather swiftly, then slowing down. Milliseconds to reach a thousand degrees, would be my guess.

Answer (score 1):

There are some papers in which Wigner effect was tested as e method of energy storage. A MORE interesting question is 'What OTHER materials can be used to store energy - how much and how fast can that energy be released?'.

The Russian patents on what is known as 'Red Mercury' are where the compound Hg2Sb2O7 is suggested and which I suspect MIGHT be based on theoretical work.

If you can produce a material that can store a LOT of Wigner energy and will also detonate would, I guess, allow all of the energy to be released VERY quickly indeed.

That said, I do not have the skillset to even estimate the veracity of the patents.